# Is there a C++ Language Feature Mark a Variable to Prevent/Warn about Later Usage in the same Scope?

Tags: c++, syntax, c++17, c++20

One of the common mistakes I find in C like code is the usage of a variable which is already consumed in the given scope. See the following fictive example function:

```cpp
std::string normalizePath(const std::string &path) {
    const auto fixedPath = fixDirectorySeparators(path);
    if (fixedPath.starts_with('/')) {
        return normalizeAbsolutePath(fixedPath);
    }
    return normalizeRelativePath(path); // use of the wrong variable.
}
```

In this simple function the problem is easy to spot, if it is more complex, it can be a source of errors.

The example above is oversimplified code to illustrate my question. The code could also look like this:

```cpp
bool isRangeERZ(int) { ... }

int calculateNextGHA(int gha, int xfactor) {
    if (xfactor > 8) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (gha < 0x8008 || xfactor == 0) {
        return gha;
    }
    if (gha > 0x10000) {
        return xfactor;
    }
    int nextGha = gha * 12 * xfactor;
    if (isRangeERZ(nextGha) && xfactor > 4) {
        return nextGha / 4;
    }
    return gha; // mistake made here
}
```

The examples have in common, they have the same type as at least one parameter and return type.

With the introduction of the move semantics in C++11, I noticed all compilers I use easily spot obvious problems like this:

```cpp
std::string moveExample() {
   auto preparedString = createText(); // moved here
   auto finalString = processText(std::move(preparedString));
   return preparedString; // compiler warns, or stops with error.
}
```

Now, I wonder: Is there a language feature or a way to get the same effect, even if the variable is copied and not moved?

It could look like this:

```cpp
std::string normalizePath(const std::string &path) {
    const auto fixedPath = fixDirectorySeparators(std::mark_as_consumed(path));
    if (fixedPath.starts_with('/')) {
        return normalizeAbsolutePath(fixedPath);
    }
    return normalizeRelativePath(path); // Compiler warns, `path` was consumed.
}
```

or like this:

```cpp
std::string normalizePath(const std::string &path) {
    const auto fixedPath = fixDirectorySeparators(path);
    std::mark_obsolete(path);
    if (fixedPath.starts_with('/')) {
        return normalizeAbsolutePath(fixedPath);
    }
    return normalizeRelativePath(path); // Compiler warns, `path` is obsolete at this point.
}
```

**Is there already a C++ language feature (or open proposal) that helps with this kind of problem?**

Comment: How is `const std::string&` consumed?

Comment: I think the only language feature that helps with such cases is functions. Move the code to a separate function and pass only the required subset of local variables.

Comment: You can use types. Give fixed paths (and/or "non-fixed" path) a seperate type (even if it is a simple wrapper around a string).

Comment: @康桓瑋 This is just an oversimplification and "consumed" is most likely the wrong word for it. I use it for lack of a better description. I like to express, that the variable was used in a way that it must not play any role in the rest of the context.

Comment: @Mat I thought about using types to prevent this, yet I found no easy solution. As the function takes the same type as input and output. Do you have a concrete method for how to use types to achieve that goal?

Comment: Functions that only deal with "fixed" paths should take "fix_path_t" as argument, to prevent calling them with plain strings. Or create a "path" type that remembers whether it's been fixed, normalized, whatever and only use that in your code except the few places where you take a path from say user input. `std::filesystem` might give you ideas.

Comment: Wrap it with `std::optional` and reset it after `fixDirectorySeparators` ends?

Comment: `std::string normalizePath(const std::string& path) { return do_normalize(fixDirectorySeparators(path)); }`. `do_normalize` doesn't see `path`, so nobody can use `path` incorrectly.

Comment: @Mat That's indeed a great solution if the kind of object is transformed from the input to the output. I see that my example is probably bad in this regard. In most cases, I deal with generic functions where no differentiation between the input parameter and output parameter is possible. Like a generic `replace` function from a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any language feature that can give you what you want. You can introduce in your application the notion of Depleted/Full objects, but I wouldn't go that way. Instead, you can write your code properly:

**Disclaimer: the example shows how to split the code logically and is not optimal.**

```
std::string normalizePath(const std::string& path)
{
    return normalizeFixedPath(fixDirectorySeparators(path));
}

std::string fixDirectorySeparators(const std::string& path) {...}

std::string normalizeFixedPath(const std::string& path) {
    if (path.starts_with('/')) {
        return normalizeAbsolutePath(path);
    }
    return normalizeRelativePath(path);
}
```

Comment: That's indeed the best solution for this oversimplified example. I added a little more complex example to illustrate my point.